# C Warning : Function was used with no prototype before its definition

Tags: c, function, prototype, warnings

I'm facing a warning while compiling a C project:

> myFunct was used with no prototype before its definition.

I do not understand this warning since the prototype is indeed before the call of the function.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
void myFunct();

int main(void)
{
   myFunct();
}

void myFunct()
{
   // Whatever
}
```

Comment: Your mistake is not saving the file after you added the prototype. Or  not showing us what you actually have.

Comment: My guess is that your "simplified code" does not quite match your non-simplified code.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling the right file? Your example compiles without warning.

Comment: I don't get any warnings from this. What compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: The warning is reproducible by adding [`-Wstrict-prototypes`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wstrict-prototypes) flag (or alternatively by [`-Wmissing-prototypes`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-prototypes)).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In C, `void myFunct();` is a function declaration, that *does not* include a prototype. It is an obsolescent feature dated back to K&R (pre-standard) C, where function calls and declarations were not checked.

Replace the declaration with:

```
void myFunct(void);
```

Comment: I can't get this code to generate this warning with gcc with -Wall -Wextra.... And different standards

Comment: As you said, I'm using an obsolescent version of C. Your suggestion fixed the warning ! Thanks

Comment: @M.Ferru: can you post details of the compiler toolchain you're using and the command line used to compile?

Comment: Yeah, *warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]*. Retracted my CV

Comment: Or -Wmissing-prototypes

Answer (score 6):

Your code provides a forward declaration for function `myFunct()`, but that declaration is not a *prototype* because it does not declare the types of the (zero) function parameters (see below).  The declaration you provide declares the function to return nothing and to accept a fixed but unspecified number of parameters,<sup>*</sup> which you will appreciate is insufficient for the compiler to fully verify the function call.  An actual prototype for that function would be this:

```
void myFunct(void);
```

Your code is nevertheless completely valid.  K&R-style function declarations are still allowed, and they satisfy C's declaration-before requirements.  They're just not good style.

---

**Details:**

[C2011 6.2.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p2) says,

> A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.

[C2011 6.7.6/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6p1) distinguishes between a "parameter type list", used in the ANSI declaration style and in particular for function prototypes, and an "identifier list", used in K&R-style declarations.  Neither can be empty, but (only) the latter can be omitted altogether, so a function declaration with empty parentheses is a K&R-style declaration, which does not provide a prototype.

---

<sup>*</sup>C++ differs from C on this.